# show toast when modal is visible in my react native project?

Tags: react-native, toast, react-native-modal

enter code hereI want to show a toast when my modal is visible in my react native project.
I use react-native-modal.
I have a button in modal when i press it should show up a toast
I don't want to put my toast tag inside the modal tag
what should i do???

```
 render(){
    return(
      <>

      <Modal visible={this.state.visible}>
      <Toast
                    ref="toast"
                    style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}
                    position='bottom'
                    positionValue={100}
                    fadeInDuration={1000}
                    fadeOutDuration={1000}
                    opacity={0.8}
                    textStyle={{color:'blue'}}
       />
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
          <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.refs.toast.show('hello world!')} style={{height:200,width:100,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
                <Text>Modal Button</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
      </Modal>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
          <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.setState({visible:true})}} style={{height:100,width:100,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'red'}}>
                <Text>button</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Actually i wanna be my toast out of my Modal tag but it show in top of screen when modal is visible

Comment: Any code sample of what you tried?

Comment: @Neeeko i put a sample

Answer (score 1):

react native modal is a native view, so impossible to be covered by a js component.